# Provide function in action’s payload for reducer

Tags: redux

I have abstract architecture with single action for handling all API calls. I want to customize it by declaring `merge` function in the payload.
For example here is a case when server response returns specific object which should be merged into existing list of objects:

```js
{
  type: 'RECEIVE_API_CALL',
  payload: {
    data: { id: 1, name: 'Altair' },
    merge: (state, newItem) => {
      const index = state.findIndex(item => item.get('id') === newItem.id);
      return state.set(index, newItem);
    }
  }
}
```

And the reducer will use that `merge` function to construct new state:

```js
case 'RECEIVE_API_CALL':
  if (action.payload.merge) {
    return action.payload.merge(state, action.payload.data);
  } else {
    return action.payload.data;
  }
```

I didn’t see functions inside payloads before. Are there any drawbacks of such approach?

Comment: What is the advantage of putting the state mutation inside your action object?  The drawback is you are now mixing concerns.  An action object describes some change and a reducer decides whether or not to act on it.

Comment: advantage is that different clients which are using API action can specify how exactly process the result of the specific call. Sometimes it should just replace local data with the server response, sometimes it should merge server response into specific place in local data

Comment: @ken4z agreed with mixing concerns. Also just realized that the action objects are not serializable because of this, and it can cause issues with middlewares.

Comment: Good point on serialization.  So if you remove the function from your action, individual clients can still decide how to process the result.  The advantage would seem to me that multiple clients can share the update logic that you are currently passing in the action.  My recommendation in this case would be to have a separate service that your clients can call if they choose that encompasses this shared logic rather than passing it in the action.